# synchronize Mouse wheel scroll for two independent windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I want two independent windows to be scroll synchronously using WIN32 C++.

Right now whichever window in focused, scroll is working for only that window. But my requirement is like, with a single scroll both the windows should scroll.

Someone suggested sending the same scroll message for other window also but MSDN says `WM_HSCROLL` message executes only for the active window.

Please suggest some resolution for this.

Below is the message sent for scrolling

```
FORWARD_WM_MOUSEWHEEL((HWND) *EegOut, x, y, zDelta, fwKeys, SendMessage);
```

After this sendmessage sends WM_HSCROLL message

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have Window1 and Window2 with mouse wheel handling procedures *handleWheelEvent1* and *handleWheelEvent2*.

Let's assume the scroll event is received by Window1. After the call to *handleWheelEvent1* in the Window1, you make your program call *handleWheelEvent2* procedure. You don't have to do the sending of the mouse wheel event.

I don't know how your code is structured but in my opinion this is the best choice.

In the reversed/mirror case is the same logic.